# List comprehension interpretation order while turning list of tuples into a list

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

Let's assume that
I have a list of tuples such as:

```
lot = [ (a,b),(c,d) ]
```

and I want to turn that into a list such as:

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

After browsing through stackoverflow, I figured out the following code would accomplish what I want to do:

```
mylist = [y for x in lot for y in x ]
```

Question:

1) how come the code breaks if I take out the part `for y in x`? I guess my question is how to interpret the clauses in the list comprehension

2) Is this the proper pythonic way to convert a list of tuples into a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to read that comprehension is to think of the solution without the comprehension. You would do:

```
>>> lot = [ ('a','b'),('c','d') ]
>>> result = []
>>> for a_tuple in lot:
...     for item in a_tuple:
...             result.append(item)
...
>>> result
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

In case of list comprehensions where two loops are involved, you just write the order of the loops exactly as in the above "non list comprehension" solution, but all in a line:

```
>>> result = [item for a_tuple in lot for item in a_tuple]
>>> result
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

This should answer why the code breaks if you take off the second loop. And yes, using list comprehensions are considered "pythonic".

Answer (score 1):

1. If you remove the part `for y in x` then in what's left: `y for x in lot` - `y` is not defined!
2. Yes, using list comprehension is considered very 'pythonic' :)

Answer (score 1):

2, yes. but maybe you like this`list(chain(*lot))`, i think it's better although not so pythonic.
because not need x and y as temp var, and more compacter.

Answer (score 1):

Nested list comprehensions loop left to right:

```
mylist = [y for x in lot for y in x ]
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this iterates through lot
                         e.g. x = ('a','b'), then x = ('c','d')


mylist = [y for x in lot for y in x ]
                         ^^^^^^^^^^ this iterates through each element in the tuple x
                                    since x = ('a', 'b'), y = 'a', then y = 'b', etc

mylist = [y for x in lot for y in x ]
          ^ this is the output
```

So in the example above:

```
    x   | y | output
--------|---|--------
 (a, b) | a | a      
 (a, b) | b | b      
 (c, d) | c | c      
 (c, d) | d | d
```